# not sure why my functions do not work

Tags: php, class, methods

I am new to php and am trying to work with functions and classes.  I am not sure why I cannot get the get and set methods to implement though.  If you could take a look and let me know where my error is I'd appreciate it.

thanks so much:

```
<?php
class fileHandling
{
function __construct(){}

public $FName="red";
public function setFName($FName){$this->FName = $FName;}
public function getFName(){if($FName == null) return "";else return $FName;}

function toString(){return "file name: ".$this->getFName();}
}


$fh = new fileHandling();
echo($fh->toString()."<br>");
$fh->setFName("purple"."<br>");
echo("color is: ".$fh->Fname."<br>");
echo($fh->getFName());
$fh->setFName("orange"."<br>");
echo("color is: ".$fh->Fname."<br>");
echo($fh->getFName());
echo($fh->toString());
?>
```

Comment: Develop with warnings on, and PHP will alert you to the problem. As an aside, `if($FName == null)` does not do exactly what you think -- you could just replace the body with `return (string)$this->FName;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function getFName(){if($this->FName == null) return "";else return $this->FName;}
```

All thing's is good but you should replace `$FName` with `$this->FName`

Comment: this might be a dumb questions but if I was using java it's type ` public String getFName(){if(FName == null) return "";else return FName;}
` to do the exact some thing.  why do I need the inclusion of the keyword this?

Answer (score 2):

getFName is missing `$this`

```
public function getFName(){
  if($this->FName == null) return "";
  else return $this->FName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here:

- `FName` !== `Fname`: So `$fh->Fname` should be `$fh->FName`;
- In your getter method you need `$this->FName` instead of `$FName`.

Comment: I had trouble finding that `Fname` with the lower-case `n`, but you're right. I'd upvote, but I've gone through all my votes for today. So for what it's worth +1 ;-)